# Subscribe to AWS IoT topic within AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-iot

I have a AWS Lambda function (triggered by an API call via API Gateway) that publishes messages to a collection of related IoT devices using an IoT topic based on the parameters received (the topic being a serial number that uniquely identifies a specific IoT device). I do this using boto3's IoT data-plane client method publish(). Is there a way for me to have this same Lambda function subscribe to the same IoT topic so that it is able to receive the response from the IoT device?

I am aware that the prescribed way for an IoT message to trigger a Lambda is to create an IoT Rule Action that calls a Lambda, however this doesn't really work for me (as far as I can tell) because what I want is for the original Lambda (the one triggered by the external API call to API Gateway) to listen for the IoT device's response and send back a HTTP response to the external caller based on that; this doesn't seem achievable if it's a separate Lambda that gets triggered when the IoT device responds on its IoT topic.  Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though not pretty, this enables me to do what I posted in my question: I added an IoT rule which flicks the IoT device's response on to a SQS queue; the Lambda (that was invoked by API Gateway to handle the request at the start) polls that SQS queue for a message which it then consumes, using it to construct and send a response back via API Gateway to the external client that sent the HTTP POST request. To be sure, this is not a great way to use AWS Lambdas, but it seems the only way available to use Lambda + API Gateway to hook up HTTP request/response with IoT publish/subscribe.

Answer (score 1):

Why does it have to be the original lambda? I'm guessing there's some state you want to save; in which case you should either persist it or pass it in the messages.

Comment: Thanks - it needs to be the original Lambda not because of internal state per se, but because that's how the external client that sends the HTTP POST request to the Lambda via API Gateway can ever get the IoT device's response as a HTTP response (to its HTTP request).  If the IoT device's response triggers a different Lambda, the original Lambda would have no way of returning the response, i.e. the external client's HTTP request would get no response or an empty response.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. What type of response are you waiting for? sounds more like you need a web socket between the device and the client.

Comment: thank you, I think you might be right there. I am currently kludging it by having an IoT rule which flicks the IoT device's response on to a SQS queue, and the Lambda polling that queue for a message which it then consumes, using it to construct and send a response back via API Gateway to the external client that sent the HTTP POST request.

Comment: @Jupiterese can't I achieve the same without using rules ? I want to write functional test to verify what message I sent on a testTopic along with the real topic .